# Objective C equivalent of byte in C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, string, char, byte

In C#

```
string p = "help";
byte myByte = (byte)p[1];
```

[In C# byte is a unsigned 8 bit integer (0-255)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx). How can achieve the same in Objective C?

The actual requirement is, I want to convert the following code segment which is written in c# to objective c. The part I can't figure out is the byte conversion.

```
static Int64 Encrypt(string p)
{       
    Int64 c = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)            
        c = c * 47 + (byte)p[i] % 97;            

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Although I don't agree with this usage due to the purpose of the type, I've seen people use `char` as a byte.

Comment: A [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C# is composed of Unicode characters (UTF-16), not bytes. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please provide example values.

Comment: @Zaph got the code sample from http://www.brkthecode.com

Comment: It could be encryption if the input length is not so long it overflows `c`. But a usable encryption method has a reasonable decryption method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilivlent to a C#:

Note: All characters are 8-bit.

```
int64_t Encrypt(NSString *p) {
    const char *cString = [p cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    unsigned long length = strlen(cString);
    int64_t c = 31;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        c = c * 47 + cString[i] % 97;

    return c;
}

NSString *p = @"help";
NSLog(@"p: %@", p);

int64_t c = Encrypt(p);
NSLog(@"c: lld", c);
```

NSLog output:

> p: help
>   c: 152006240

Comment: Both C# string and NSString use Unicode encoding (but not exactly the same byte layout). C# version uses only the lower byte, your ObjC version changes encoding beforehand. This version will only works for single byte text input.

Comment: @9dan Which I clearly state. The OP also states "unsigned 8 bit integer (0-255)". But things get really strange it UTF-16 is assumed for several reasons including surrogate pairs and plane 1 characters such as emoji. If you look at my edit 4 history you will see my initial answer concerning unicode and ASCII.

Comment: @9dan Look at the [web page cited](http://www.brkthecode.com) by the OP. The answer code produces the correct result for the sample case: "abacus" -> 334160560256.

Comment: @Zaph I apologize if my comment upset you. I might chose wrong words by mistake. Just want to add a footnote regarding multibyte complications.

Comment: @9dan Trust me, I am not upset. Your comments are correct but not in the context of this particular question. unicode is in general poorly understood and the implementations generally bad for surrogate pairs and plane 1 characters.